# What does Parenizor mean?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

From the famous [article by Douglas Crockford on JavaScript inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html):

> *First, we will make a **Parenizor** class that will have set and get
>   methods for its value, and a toString method that will wrap the value
>   in parens.*
>
> ```
> function Parenizor(value) {
>     this.setValue(value);
> }
> ... etc
> ```

Is it just like "Foo" a name placeholder without meaning? Or is "Parenizor" a computer term like "singleton"? Or is it an incredible obvious pun that I am missing?

Yes I googled it. You try. :-)

Comment: it sounds like since it's wrapping the value in parens, it's a 'paren'-izor. '-ize' means "to cause to become or become like something specified : to become or become like (something specified)", so it seems like a pun :P

Comment: _Paren_ is short for _parentheses_, and _izor_ is a misspelling of the normal English suffix used for an agent that changes something to a given state.

Comment: duh! LOL! of course. Thanks

Comment: If you make a parentheses remover class would it then be a `Parenator`?

Comment: it's Doug-ese. yeah, go with it. the man invented "truthy" before colbert got his pubes...

Comment: @jongware Reparenator? ha!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260563/jesse) and [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)

**Paren** is short for parentheses, and **izor** is a misspelling of the normal English suffix used for an agent that changes something to a given state.

So since it's wrapping the value in **parens**, it's a '**paren**'-**izor**. :-) LOL!

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct about the origin of the name.

> Is it just like "Foo" a name placeholder without meaning?

Yes, it could be named anything.

The reason he uses a capital `Parenizor` is because it is the standard javascript idiom to name functions you are going to use as a class with a capital. Since javascript doesn't have a way to actually differentiate between a one off function and a class function.

In other words it's purely for the benefit of the programmer and future programmers who read the code and doesn't change the behavior of the function from standard in any way.